# Video in html and Java wicket

Tags: html

I want to add video in HTML page.I don't want to use html5 as I need to use the HTML in Java wicket.
I used iframe but there are some issues.
Can anyone who has worked on the same provide me details on how many ways are there to achieve the same.
Thanks.
I there any sample project link for same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HTML5 video with Wicket? 
[like this](http://mysticcoders.com/blog/integrating-html5-and-wicket/)

Comment: I can try html5. so core requirement is that I need to show a video from remote url in our application in html page and on a link click I need to show the same video in a separate window , a modal window is ok. Can we use iframe for the same or we have some better options.